# NuGet restore not including framework

Tags: .net, msbuild, nuget

I have a .NET solution with some projects running in Visual Studio 2015. I'm handling some of my external libraries through NuGet.

NuGet packages are located in `packages` folder as they should. If I delete the `packages` folder and rebuild with either VS or through command-line msbuild the `packages` folder is restored in this kind of hierarchy: `packages\Csv.2.0.0.0\lib\Csv.dll`. The folders are missing the framework and whole solution's references are created without the framework folder.

If my colleague builds the same project, NuGet restores the same packages with the framework folder, such as `packages\Csv.2.0.0.0\lib\net40\Csv.dll` and his references fail. Same thing happens if we run restore manually: `nuget restore mysolution.sln`

What causes this problem and how could we fix it? As far as I've understood, the framework folder should always be there. Our source codes are the same, VS versions are the same, nuget.config files are the same, nuget.exe version is the same (3.4.4.1321).

Comment: Feels like a werid bug. Can you open an issue at http://github.com/nuget/home with detailed repro?

Comment: I'm just quite convinced that it's a pebcak problem as I'm not very familiar with nuget. And actually just with one library, as I just noticed. My next goal is to get rid of that dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue fixed by removing one of my packages (turns out it wasn't really needed). As it was only one package that was causing the problem, I guess the original problem had something to do with either the package's configurations or with how it was added in our nuget.

Anyway, problem solved. Other packages work just fine.